# How to understand this output of ip route list table 255

Tags: linux, ip, route, iproute2

```
broadcast 100.125.71.152 dev rmnet_data1  proto kernel  scope link  src 100.125.71.153 
local 100.125.71.153 dev rmnet_data1  proto kernel  scope host  src 100.125.71.153 
broadcast 100.125.71.155 dev rmnet_data1  proto kernel  scope link  src 100.125.71.153 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
```

What's means of `broadcast` `local` ? Why is not show the netmask? Look there is show gateway ipaddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
```

It is broadcast of loopback subnet. The more info you'll find in this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934834/udp-broadcast-address-127-255-255-255